# advanced search functionality - query builder for the end-user

Tags: javascript, php, sql, search, builder

I'd like to implement an "adavanced search" function into my website. It is a database application and therefore uses a mySQL database.

I was looking for a tool called query builder/ composer/ generator/ constructor ...
The user should be able to narrow down his/her search. I've done an internet search on my own for such tools and stumbled across many, but most of them are more like tools for programmers to support them writing SQL queries.

I stumbled across these two tools that do what I am looking for:

- EasyQuery/ EasyQuery.js (e.g. http://advangle.com/)
- RedQueryBuilder (http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/)

Do you know more of them? I'd like to use PHP as programming language (Javascript in addition is okay). Open source and free is preferred.

Furthermore my data base structure (I only want to search one specific table) does not change dynamically over time.

Maybe you can also guide me to different keywords I have to look for to find other tools like those mentioned above.

Thanks,
Matthias

(PS: Please don't discuss security issues like SQL injections and so on.)

Comment: What have *you* tried so far?

Comment: Putting the SQL statements together by hand so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I dont know about redQuery Builder but know about EasyQuery. EasyQuery as name suggest is so easy to integrate. Its free also. It is available in .NET version , javascript version and PHP version. You just need to do some changes for database in its controller.